# recyclerview showing empty white screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am developing news app using kotlin but it is showing empty white screen and there is no error or exception on the logcat

below my SportNewsAdapter.kt

> ```
> class SportNewsAdapter(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SportNewsAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
>
>     var articleList : List<Article> = listOf()
>
>     override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
>
>         val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.news_list,parent,false)
>         return MyViewHolder(view)
>     }
>
>     override fun getItemCount(): Int {
>         return articleList.size
>     }
>
>     override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
>
>         holder.tvMovieName.text = articleList.get(position).title
>         Glide.with(context).load(articleList.get(position).urlToImage)
>             .apply(RequestOptions().centerCrop())
>             .into(holder.image)
>     }
>
>     fun setMovieListItems(movieList: List<Article>){
>         this.articleList = articleList;
>         notifyDataSetChanged()
>     }
>
>     class MyViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView!!) {
>
>         val tvMovieName: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.title)
>         val image: ImageView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.image)
>
>     }
> }
> ```

below news_item.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="150dp"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/image"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/title"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>         android:textStyle="bold"
>         android:textSize="20sp"
>         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
>
> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

below MainActivity.kt

> ```
> class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
>
>     lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
>     lateinit var sportNewsAdapter: SportNewsAdapter
>
>
>     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
>         recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
>         sportNewsAdapter = SportNewsAdapter(this)
>         recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
>         recyclerView.adapter = sportNewsAdapter
>
>
>         val apiInterface = SportNewsInterface.create().getNews()
>
>
>         apiInterface.enqueue( object : Callback<List<Article>> {
>             override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Article>>?, response: Response<List<Article>>?) {
>
>                 if(response?.body() != null)
>                     sportNewsAdapter.setMovieListItems(response.body()!!)
>             }
>
>             override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Article>>?, t: Throwable?) {
>
>             }
>         })
>     }
>     }
> ```

below activity_main.xml

> ```
> <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
>     android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
> ```

below SportNewsInterface.kt

> interface SportNewsInterface {
>
> ```
> @GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
> fun getNews() : Call <List<Article>>
>
> companion object {
>
>     var BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"
>
>     fun create() : SportNewsInterface {
>
>         val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
>             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
>             .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
>             .build()
>         return retrofit.create(SportNewsInterface::class.java)
>
>     }
> } }
> ```

below SportNewsResponse.kt where implemented retrofit

```
data class SportNewsResponse(
    val articles: List<Article>,
    val status: String,
    val totalResults: Int
)
```

Comment: Check your `news_item.xml`

Comment: checked changed the still the same

Answer (score 0):

Change recycler view height to wrap content and run  again

Comment: @Edgar Shvedsky check whether articleList.size in getItemCount returns correct size.

Comment: @Edgar Shvedskiy just print and see what value is actually returning there.

Comment: how can I print there

Comment: ```Log.v("article size",":"+articleList.size);```                     add this in your getItemCount() and see your Logcat...@Edgar Shvedskiy

Comment: yodgorbek.komilov.musobaqayangiliklari D/onFailure: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Post your log message for that @Edgar Shvedskiy